# Auto Incrementing In Another Table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, primary-key, auto-increment

I am trying to see how to auto-increment a PK from another table.

**For example:**

I have two tables where UserID is present. A User table where UserID is the primary key & a Ticket table where UserID is a reference. When a row is inserted into the User table,  the UserID is incremented (of course). When a row is inserted into the Ticket table, I want the UserID to increment in the Ticket & User table as well. For the Ticket table, should I just have it in my PHP where I add 1 to the last inserted ID in the User Table or is there something in the database where I can set to do this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *When a row is inserted into the Ticket table, I want the UserID to increment in the Ticket & User table as well.*

It seems your table relation is not defined correct.

If the tables are:
 1. `User` with `userid` as auto incremented primary key, and
 2. `Ticket` with `userid` as referenced key from user

then, before inserting into `Ticket` you should have `userid` value in hand. Because it has a foreign key relation, you can't generate it new but pick from `user` table and use in `ticket` table.

And incrementing the `userid` value in `ticket` table has no meaning so long as it has a foreign key relation.